# Is it possible w/ the Google Hangouts API to get the text from all messages ever sent to and from a person?

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

I've went through the API documentation but cannot find what I'm looking for. Basically, I want to get all messages that I have received or sent to a person on my hangouts/google chat; is this possible?